# Delphi 10.3 Android 9 save downloaded data to shared download folder

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Delphi 10.3.1 Rio. I have made an app that self updates. The app downloads the APK from a site using HTTPS as required with Android 9. I have used this for 2 years now with Delphi 10.2.3. This works fine. I use `System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath, apnavn);` to get the path to download to.

I do read with `TIdHTTP` before and now the new `TNetHTTPClient`, as the old does not support HTTPS as required with Android 9. I am granted access to external storage. I download to a `TMemoryStream`, and save to the shared downloads path. Then I execute an `Intent` to update the app.

This works fine on Android 6, but does not save the file on Android 9. I have tried to request permission to `TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`, but this is not asked, and not granted. I have searched the Internet without finding any solution. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Does it show any error messages? Have you used a logcat viewer to check the messages logged by the device? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: What does your code look like to request the permission and execute the intent? And FYI, TIdHTTP DOES support HTTPS on Android, but on Android 6+ you have to deploy the OpenSSL libs with your app, as Google has dropped support for OpenSSL at the OS level.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permission to save data into shared downloads path? I'm no expert for Android but I doubt `TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` gives you permission for that.

Comment: The code for asking permission is standard, and works. I ca't find any specific permission for writing to shared download, but I have permission to write to external disk, and it works. The downloading works, data is read in a memory stream, but saving the stream to a file in download does not save anything. No error message. Trying to save in shared documents without permission gives the same result, no file exists after save. TidHTTP does not work for https on my unit, but TNetHTTPclient does. The problem is just saving to shared download fram Tmemorystream.

Comment: Did you try it with a minimal app, containing no HTTPS download, and only a simple TFileStream.Create(...) to write to GetSharedDownloadsPath?

Comment: Android 9 did fool me, the downloaded file was saved, but not visible in "files" other was visible. Do not know why. 
Next, it is the running of install apk that is failing without telling me why.
I will thank all for trying to help. Android 9 do have some tricks hiding what is really there.